# customizing user permissions in alfresco?

Tags: alfresco, content-management-system

Am a newbie to alfresco, I am using Alfresco 3.2 Enterprise Edition. I have a task that I need to give permissions for the built in user roles. For example, Consumer can view the folder,view content, invite others and Take the ownership. I had a look at permissionDefinitions.xml, but still struggling in assigning persmissions. Please help me in this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. What exactly do you need to do? Assign permissions to who to do what?

Comment: I have created a new role called "CopyEditor" and given the permissions as WriteContent,ReadPermissin,Consumer,CheckOut. ie., same as editor but instead of write permission, I've give WriteContent. But the change is not taking place in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

- Create your own permission
- Create you own permissionGroup
- Set your permissionGroup under permissionSet type="cm:folder" tag to see you permissions once you are trying to invite a user to a folder.

Thanks